# Tikz patterns library and pst-plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, incompatibility, pst-plot

The following outputs a blank page:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=dots] (0,0) rectangle (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It seems that there is an issue between `pst-plot` and `patterns` library. Is that a known issue?

(I discovered the issue by manually commenting out code blocks. Could I have discovered it from the log files? I ask because there was no error message.)

Comment: Please post your log here. Hopefully there's a warning.

Comment: Well I wouldn't comment lines one by one but by blocks. But beside this if the log-file doesn't give an indication about what is wrong I would as first step minimalize the document.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Assuming that the problem actually shows with such a small document body (I have some doubts about this).

Comment: Discovered the source; edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Your example works fine here, with an up to date TeX Live 2016.

Comment: It works fine also on Overleaf, please update your distribution!

Comment: I have the problem both in my local setup (MikTeX on Windows 7 64 bit) and Sharelatex.

Comment: Which engine do you use to compile? And do you really use standalone in your actual document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a comment that an answer but too long for a comment.

If you put `\listfiles` before your code, in your log you'll see the package versions packages you're using.

On ShareLaTeX your MWE doesn't work, they have this package versions:

```
 *File List*
standalone.cls    2015/07/15 v1.2 Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2015/07/15 v1.2 Default configuration file for 'standalone' c
lass
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2016/10/09 v1.0u Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2017/01/12 v0.06k Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
pst-plot.sty    2011/04/13 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex (hv)
pstricks.sty    2015/11/14 v0.62 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
pstricks.tex    2016/12/23 v2.71 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2016/12/23 v2.71 `PST-fp' (hv)
pst-xkey.sty    2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
 multido.sty    2004/05/17 package wrapper for PSTricks `multido.tex', (HV/RN)
 multido.tex    2010/05/14 v1.42 `multido' (tvz,hv)
pst-plot.tex    2017/01/18 1.76 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv)
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

I have an updated TeX Live 2016, if I run your MWE, it works, with these package
versions:

```
 *File List*
standalone.cls    2015/07/15 v1.2 Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2015/07/15 v1.2 Default configuration file for 'standalone' c
lass
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2016/10/09 v1.0u Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2017/01/12 v0.06k Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
pst-plot.sty    2011/04/13 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex (hv)
pstricks.sty    2017/03/17 v0.63 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
pstricks.tex    2017/04/06 v2.72 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2017/04/06 v2.72 `PST-fp' (hv)
pst-xkey.sty    2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
 multido.sty    2004/05/17 package wrapper for PSTricks `multido.tex', (HV/RN)
 multido.tex    2010/05/14 v1.42 `multido' (tvz,hv)
pst-plot.tex    2017/03/20 1.77 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv)
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

As you can see, the `pst-plot` versions differ:

```
pst-plot.tex    2017/03/20 1.77 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv) <-- mine
pst-plot.tex    2017/01/18 1.76 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv) <-- ShareLaTeX
```

You have to update your TeX distribution.